# AFNetworking 2.0: How to pass complete json param argument converted as base64encoded + urlencoded string for AFNetworking 2.0 Post Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, afnetworking-2, url-encoding

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 & new to it. Tried couple of sample WS calls with success. We have Web Service implemented & to be called like:

It's data parameter is encrypted string.

Request is: http://demo.XYZ.net/getlanguage   // Just for example

Parameters:

1) first you need to crate json with parameter    like below
   dictionary to string

```
   {
       param =     {
           pone = "com.xyz";
           ptwo = 68208;
           pthree = eda24e95f;
       };
   }
```

to

```
   {"param":{"pone":"com.xyz","ptwo":"68208","pthree":"eda24e95f"}}
```

2) and then convert json string into the base64encode

```
   something like: eyJob21lIjp7InNGFlMGEzZDg1Mzg3YTNkYmFlZDQ5MzBiMCIsInNhbHQiOiI3OTU2IiwicGFj5uY19
```

3) and then convert string into the urlencode then send encrypted
   string in "data" with post method

**eyJob21lIjp7InNpZ24iOiJiZmU4Y2RmZGEzZDg1Mzg3YTNkYmFlZDQ5MzBiMCIsInNhbHQi%0AOiI3OTU2IiwicGFja2FnZSI6ImNvbS5uYmJk**

Then Finally Pass that encoded string as below:

http://demo.XYZ.net/getlanguage?data=**eyJob21lIjp7InNpZ24iOiJiZmU4Y2RmZGEzZDg1Mzg3YTNkYmFlZDQ5MzBiMCIsInNhbHQi%0AOiI3OTU2IiwicGFja2FnZSI6ImNvbS5uYmJk**

Above WS is perfectly working.[Checked on **"POSTMan-Chrome-Extension"**]

The question is how to implement same with AFNetworking 2.0 ? where to encrypt using params like above when we use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is really what your server requires, you can simply convert the original `param` dictionary to JSON using `NSJSONSerialization` and then base64 encode it with `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`. Having done that, you can build your new parameters dictionary with that string:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://demo.XYZ.net/getlanguage";

NSDictionary *originalParameters = @{@"param" : @{
                                             @"pone"   : @"com.xyz",
                                             @"ptwo"   : @68208,
                                             @"pthree" : @"eda24e95f"
                                             }
                                     };

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:originalParameters options:0 error:&error];
NSAssert(jsonData, @"JSON encoding failed: %@", error);

NSString *base64EncodedString = [jsonData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"data" : base64EncodedString};

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager GET:urlString parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * __nonnull task, id __nonnull responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * __nonnull task, NSError * __nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}];
```

If you're using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, the basic idea is the same: Convert dictionary of parameters to JSON, base64 encode it, and then create new parameter dictionary for that and supply it to the `GET` method.